# Why is my virtual function not being called?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with virtual methods. When I call `f` it doesn't work. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
   virtual void f() const { std::cout << "In A"; }
   virtual ~A() {};
};

struct B : A {
   void f() const { std::cout << "In B"; }
};

int main()
{
   A* a = new A();

   B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);

   (*b).f();


   delete a;
}
```

It doesn't print anything at all, and I don't get any errors. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Always check the result of a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: B is an A, but A is not a B.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is wrong is you did not check if retuned pointer is `NULL`.

`dynamic_cast` tells you if the actual object pointed by `a` is of the type `b`, which it is obviously not. And in such a scenario it will return you a `NULL`.

Basically, You are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, causing an **Undefined Behavior** which unluckily for you doesn't crash.

When you use a language provided feature it should be used in the way mandated by the standard. The use of `dynamic_cast` warrants a `NULL` check of the returned pointer.

Your pointer `a` should actually point to an derived class object `b`. You need:

```
   A* a = new B();
   B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
```

Also, your code **must** check the returned pointer:

```
   if(b != NULL)
       (*b).f();
```

Comment: And if you prefer not to check for `NULL` (but why wouldn't you?) you can `dynamic_cast` to a reference type instead; then failed casts will throw an exception instead of returning `NULL`.

Answer (score 7):

This line:

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
```

gives you a null pointer, since `a` does not in fact point at a `B`.

The following line is then Undefined Behavior.  (You were "lucky" that nothing at all happened.)

Comment: @David, With a valid `B` object.

Comment: @David You can't "fix it". You're trying to make a `B` out of an `A`, but that doesn't work since an `A` is not a `B`. Maybe you actually meant to do it the other way round?

Comment: I would rather rephrase *"You were **"lucky"** that nothing at all happened."* to *"You were **"unlucky"** that nothing at all happened."*

Comment: @AlokSave I understand your point, but as long as it's in scare quotes.

Comment: Fair enough. Guess I missed the quotes being *scare quotes* :-)